# How to make a Walkthrough Introduction Slider in Ionic Vue Application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic-vue

I have seen most of the mobile application has an intro slider when we first time installs the app.
I searched on google but all of them are old version of Ionic with Angular.

I'm very confused about where to put the component and how should I manage the state.

I'm using Capacitor in my application and I think the capacitor has storage.

I also want to know what is the proper flow of doing this thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use swiper.js. https://swiperjs.com/vue

Comment: take a look at this post - https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/ionic-framework-vuejs-and-dynamic-slides-using-swiperjs-hk4 leave comment if you have question

Comment: I think swiper.js  should be a good choice for this kind of thing. Next how should I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

To remember or track if the slider was shown before you have to store some kind of information to the device. You can use the `localStorage` or [capacitor storage](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage) plugin. I will recommend using the plugin as localStorage data might get removed by the operating system or user after some time.

Here is the process to achieve this using the plugin.

#### Install and sync the plugin

If you are using the Capacitor version 2 or less, you don't have to install it.

```sh
npm install @capacitor/storage
npx cap sync
```

#### Use it like this

```js
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/storage';

const { value } = Storage.get({
  key: 'introShowed',
});

if (!value) {
  // logic to show the intro goes here

  // set the value to true so next time this code block will not be executed
  Storage.set({
    key: 'introShowed',
    value: true,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When main layout is created you can store an value to Storage.
And after that you can check for it.